# Phonegap App fixes itself to wrong orientation

Tags: android, cordova, orientation

I am using Phonegap 3.4.0 to develop an Android app that is to be fixed in landscape. I did the setting in config.xml

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

On screens up to 9 inches i got the app to fix to landscape as expected but on smaller screens <= 7 inches thereabout, the app fixes itself to portrait. I need it to be landscape on all devices and screen sizes.

Has anyone had this experience before and how may I solve this please? Thanks in advance

UPDATE: my AndroidManifest.xml file, the parts that may be affect display I think

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">

   <activity                   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"           android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:name="my_app_name" 
     android:screenOrientation="userLandscape"     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I have also noticed that it stays portrait on some devices that have higher screen sizes as well. Could this be about my phonegap version?

Comment: android:screenOrientation="userLandscape" ..

Try landscape. both are still but userLandscape seems to be not working in phonegap sometimes. (src : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5634)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried checking your manifest file ?

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
      <activity
            android:name="Your App Name"   
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:label="@string/activity_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" // set your prefered orientation
      </activity>
 </application>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with relevant lines from my AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Also I noticed that in Phonegap 3.4.0 that I use and maybe later, the manifest file is generated automatically when the app is built so editing the manifest files makes no difference. I may need other approches here pls

Comment: Looks like you are editing the manifest inside bin folder. Don't do that. You have to edit which is outside bin.